# How to clear all declared variable using JQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am using Laravel-5.8 and JQuery:

This is my view blade

```html
<table class=" table table-bordered table-striped table-hover datatable datatable-employee">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Goal Type
      </th>
      <th width="12%">
        &nbsp;
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($goals as $key => $goal)
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{$goal->goaltype->name ?? '' }}
      </td>
      <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Click To Add Comment">
                                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#comment_emp{{ $goal->id }}" data-original-title="Comment"> 
                                       <i class="fas text-white">Add Comment</i>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

From the code, user will click on Add Comment () to initiate this modal form

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="comment_emp{{ $goal->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form action="{{route('appraisal.appraisal_year_end_setups.employee_year_end_comment',['id'=>$goal->id])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="review_comment-form">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="modal-header">
          Self-Review Comment
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label"> Rating:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="hidden" id="myRatingLimit" value="{{ $goal->goaltype->ratingLimit ? $goal->goaltype->ratingLimit->max_rating : '' }}">
            <input type="hidden" id="myWeightedScore" value="{{$goal->weighted_score ?? '' }}">
            <!--<input  type="text" name="employee_year_end_weighted_score" placeholder="Enter Rating here" class="form-control" required>-->
            <input type="text" id="myRating" name="employee_year_end_weighted_score" class="form-control myRating" placeholder="Enter Rating here e.g. 10" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
              style="width: 100%;" maxlength="4" onkeyup="checkScore(this.value)" onkeypress="allowNumbersOnly(event)" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" id="review_comment_btn-submit" class="btn btn-success btn-ok">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  function checkScore(value) {
    let main = $("#myWeightedScore").val();
    let perc = $("#myRatingLimit").val();
    main = main ? parseInt(main) : 0;
    perc = perc ? parseInt(perc) : 0;
    let sumWeightBalance = parseInt(main);
    let sumPercBalance = parseInt(perc);
    var percVal = (sumPercBalance / 100).toFixed(2); //its convert 10 into 0.10
    var mult = main * percVal; 
    var percResult = main + mult;
    let sumValue = parseInt(value);
    console.log(sumWeightBalance);
    console.log(sumPercBalance);
    console.log(percVal);
    console.log(mult);
    console.log(sumValue);

    if (sumValue > percResult) {
      Swal('Oops...', 'Self Rating is greater than Rating Limit!', 'error')
      $("#myRating").val('');
      return false;
    }
    sumWeightBalance.val('');
  } <
  /script>    <
  script type = "text/javascript" >
  function allowNumbersOnly(e) {
    var code = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (code > 31 && (code < 48 || code > 57)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }; <
/script>
```

I observed that each time the modal form is ninitiated, it still retain the former values of:

```
    console.log(sumWeightBalance);
    console.log(sumPercBalance);
    console.log(percVal);
    console.log(mult);
    console.log(sumValue);
```

and this affects the result of my calculation.

How do I clear each of these values before the modal form is rendered?

Thanks

I changed the JQuery to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkScore(el) {
        let modal = $(el).closest(".modal-dialog");
        let main = modal.find(".myWeightedScore").val();
        let perc = $(".myRatingLimit").val();
        main = main ? parseInt(main) : 0;
        perc = perc ? parseInt(perc) : 0;
        let sumWeightBalance = parseInt(main);
        let sumPercBalance = parseInt(perc);
        var percVal = (sumPercBalance / 100).toFixed(2); //its convert 10 into 0.10
         var mult = main * percVal; 
         var percResult = main + mult;
        let sumValue = parseInt(el);
        console.log(sumWeightBalance);
        console.log(sumPercBalance);
        console.log(percVal);
        console.log(mult);
        console.log(sumValue);
        if (sumValue > percResult) {
            Swal('Oops...', 'Self Rating is greater than Rating Limit!', 'error')
            $(".myRating").val('');
            return false;
        }
       }
</script>
```

Comment: At least when using `let` the variables` scope is limited to your `checkScore()` function. When does this function run ? When your modal opens ? On submit ? Do you reset your input fields after submitting / closing  the modal ?

Comment: The issue isn't the variables as they're scoped already.  It's because `$("#myWeightedScore")` (etc) isn't being cleared / set.  Because **IDs must be unique in the document** `$("#myWeightedScore")` always gets the input from the *first* dialog.  Also your `checkScore` doesn't have any context - ie doesn't know it's supposed to be looking at dialog `comment_emp{{ $goal->id }}`

Comment: @freedomn-m - Please can you give a sample from my code

Comment: Please what do I do?

Comment: Sorry, it's too long to give a decent answer right now, someone else may pick it up.  Essentially, change `onkeyup="checkScore(this.value)"` to `onkeyup="checkScore(this)"` and your `checkScore` function to `checkScore(el)` then `let modal = $(el).closest(".modal-dialog"); let main = modal.find(".myWeightedScore").val();` and remove all the duplicated IDs and replace with classes, eg `<input class='myWeightedScore..`

Comment: @freedomn-m - Is there no other way you can help?

Comment: @freedomn-m - See my editted code

Comment: You need to do the `modal.find` change for all the inputs

Comment: @freedomn-m - How? Kindly give samples?

Comment: Same as `let main = modal.find(".myWeightedScore").val();` but for all the other inputs: `let perc = modal.find(".myRatingLimit").val();` etc

Comment: @freedomn-m - Please help.  It's not validating again.  See the jquery:         function checkScore(el) {
        let modal = $(el).closest(".modal-dialog");
        let main = modal.find(".myWeightedScore").val();
        let perc = modal.find(".myRatingLimit").val();
        main = main ? parseInt(main) : 0;
        perc = perc ? parseInt(perc) : 0;
        let sumWeightBalance = parseInt(main);
        let sumPercBalance = parseInt(perc);
        var percVal = (sumPercBalance / 100).toFixed(2);
        var mult = main * percVal; 
        var percResult = main + mult;